# Uppercase accented characters displayed as "?"

Tags: accents, font-encodings, input-encodings, latin-modern, french

The header is

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=4cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\begin{document}
MÈRE
\end{document}
```

In the TeX file, for example when I write `é` it is well displayed in the pdf output file, but `É` is displayed as "?". Why? Yet the character `É` [is well supported by the encoding T1 (for fontenc)](http://www.micropress-inc.com/fonts/encoding/t1.htm). The problem seems to be only with uppercase accented characters.

The problem also seems to be from `latin1` of the package `inputenc`. I tried `utf8` instead of `latin1` but it does not match.

NB: I know the alternative `\'E` and it work well, but I want to write the character directly as `É`.

**EDIT:** with the above header everything works fine on my Windows 7 PC, the problem only on my Windows XP one.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it does not match? Please provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is very difficult to help otherwise. However, the best will certainly be to switch to using `utf8` but you need to resave your file in the correct encoding as well. The encoding of your file needs to match the option you feed `inputenc`. So if you use `latin1`, your file must use that encoding as well. If you use `utf8`, your file must use that. I suspect that your file encoding does not match.

Comment: What is your editor and how is it configured, as regards the font encoding?

Comment: @cfr: Right, I have to change the encoding of my Tex file to UTF-8. The best way is using Notepad++ editor. Target encoding must be "UTF-8 (without BOM)".

Comment: Why everything works already fine on Windows 7 but not on Windows XP ?

Comment: @seinus the operating system is not relevant but your editor may be configured to use different default encodings (utf8 or iso-8859-1) in the two systems. You can use either encoding but the encoding specified to `inputenc` needs to match the encoding actually used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just verified, under my Windows 7 PC, the encoding of the tex source file is ANSI and with the above header everything works well, i.e, ``É`` is correctly displayed in the pdf output file. I didn't understand how !

Comment: @seinus `ANSI` is a misnaming (by microsoft) the encoding is not specified by ansi. ANSI is (was) the US arm of ISO and it's an international encoding iso-8859-1 informally known by everyone except microsoft as latin1, so if windows says the file encoding is ansi then declare it to inputenc as latin1

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The encoding is ANSI and with the above header (latin1), the accented uppercase character is displayed as "?" in the pdf output file without any reported error or warning in compilation !

Comment: @seinus you still have not provided an example file, _every_ question should include a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem. In this case you should be able to cut your file down to just a few lines that print a `?` and also include the full log in code (`{}`) sections in the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can I know the current encoding of my Tex file and how can I change it from Texniccenter ? Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't know that editor, sorry.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Anyway, thank you very much for your continuous help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David Carlisle said, it must work with pdflatex as well. Probably you editor uses `utf8` by default, and the declared input encoding and the real one must coincide. So declare`utf8` encoding and use the `Latin Modern` fonts (don't load fontenc in that case, since the `lmodern` package does it for you):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=4cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\begin{document}
MÈRE
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Seinus/ As far as I know, TeXnic Center encodes in utf8 by default, so you should declare utf8, not latin 1. Anyway, it's better for portability. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [XeTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX).

you can compile this MWE with `xelatex` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=4cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\begin{document}

ALLONS MANGER GRAND-MÈRE.

ALLONS MANGER, GRAND-MÈRE.

\end{document}
```

So you will get a fine output.

Comment: Thank you for this response. If the Tex file is ANSI coded then all accented characters will not be displayed on the pdf. Your proposal seems to be valid only for UTF-8 coded source file. Thanks again.

Comment: xetex is a possibility but of course you don't need to use xetex you can type accented letters with classic tex and pdftex as well!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "you can type accented letters with classic tex and pdftex as well": only while using UTF-8 encoder, right ?

Comment: @seinus not just utf8, any encoding supported by inputenc eg latin1 (is0-8859-1)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But latin1 doesn't work, uppercase accented character like "É" is not displayed (without any reported error or warning). This is the main problem.

Comment: @seinus if the encoding that is used used to save the file matches the encoding declared to inputenc it will work, if the encoding declared to inputenc is wrong then it won't work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but I have a very strange case: ANSI saved file and latin1 in the header, but uppercase character is displayed as "? " in the pdf output file without any reported error or warning in compilation !