# How to remove accents when using \MakeUppercase for Greek?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, accents

I would like to know if it is possible to not print accents in capital letters that have been produced using the \MakeUppercase command.

I am using XeLaTeX, and the fontspec package in case this matters.

This is an example of a document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
    \MakeUppercase{Πλούταρχος}
 \end{document}
```

This will produce: 
[image: ΠΛΟΎΤΑΡΧΟΣ] instead of [image: ΠΛΟΥΤΑΡΧΟΣ]

Is it a font thing? Is there any alternative that would not print the accents?

Comment: Have you tried if the `textcase` package helps? Just a wild guess though...

Comment: Yes, same behavior when using \MakeTextUppercase

Comment: I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414802/how-to-make-uppercase-work-with-polish-language/414804#4148049), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286966/incomplete-generation-of-greek-letters-with-unicode-and-xelatex) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200083/uppercase-accented-characters-displayed-as/200088), maybe that helps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two possible approaches at least. First, you can use the `expl3` case changer with it's support for Greek:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:Npn \MakeUppercase #1 { \text_uppercase:nn { el } {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
    \MakeUppercase{Πλούταρχος}
 \end{document}
```

Second, the `xgreek` package is available and adjusts some internal data to get the mapping you would like

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\begin{document}
    \MakeUppercase{Πλούταρχος}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: A quick question, if you may: what does `el` mean? Where can I find a list of the available languages for `\text_uppercase:nn`? Thanks

Comment: @TheDrunkenWhaler The language here is ISO 639-1 (at least at present).  There are only a few that need special treatment that I know of (Greek, Dutch, Lithuanian, Turkish, Armenian); if the language is not know, you get the default (Unicode) treatment.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I found a list [here][1] in case someone needs.
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Comment: Thanks! the xgreek package did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

The `\uppercase` primitive uses `\lccode` of each character to create the uppercase variant. So, you can set `\uccode` of all accented variants as their non-accented counterparts. For example in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[newcm]

Πλούταρχος

\uccode`ύ=`Υ
\uppercase{Πλούταρχος} % prints: ΠΛΟΥΤΑΡΧΟΣ

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `\usepackage[greek]{babel}`, preferably after fontspec package, in the preamble, it resolves the problem.