# How to remove diacritics from uppercase greek in TOC and headings?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, greek, uppercase

The solution to [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523691/how-to-remove-accents-when-using-makeuppercase-for-greek/523707#523707?newreg=71d2013886e14c6d9bbdb49eb7d2853b) partially solves the issue, but uppercase greek words are still appearing with diacritics in the table of contents.

Is there any other way around this?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset:Npn \MakeUppercase #1 { \text_uppercase:nn { el } {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\usepackage{Alegreya}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Alegreya}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{ἄνθρωπος}
\chapter{ἀνδρεία}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably using the optional argument of `\chapter` without diacritics. Why don't you want diacritics in the table of contents and headers?

Comment: @Bernard, it looks strange with diacritics. Ideally they would loose the diacritics if the header happens to be in uppercase, and keep them if they are in lowercase. Simply writing them without the diacritics would mean further adjustments if I change the headings setting down the road.