# Command \MakeUppercase does not work as expected in pdfLatex, but works fine in LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX

Tags: unicode, accents, latex-base, uppercase

As you can see from the minimal working examples below `\MakeUppercase` command when compiled with pdfLatex keeps accents for converted Uppercase words, although it shouldn't. When compiled with Lualatex or Xelatex works fine. How can I fix it when working with pdfLatex?

MWE1: pdfLaTeX

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{calc}  
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,247mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}  
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}  

\begin{document}      
Πρόταση για έλεγχο των τόνων στα κεφαλαία  
    
\MakeUppercase{Πρόταση για έλεγχο των τόνων στα κεφαλαία}  
\end{document}
```

output from pdfLatex:

[image: output1]

But "almost" the same code if compiled with LuaLatex (or XeLatex) works just fine: the accents are not present on uppercase words:

MWE2: LuaLaTeX

```
% !TeX program = lualatex  
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{calc}  
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,247mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}  
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}  
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,   Script=Greek}\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Scale=1.1}  
\setmainfont{GFS Artemisia}  
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}  

\begin{document}  
Πρόταση για έλεγχο των τόνων στα κεφαλαία  

\MakeUppercase{Πρόταση για έλεγχο των τόνων στα κεφαλαία}  
\end{document}
```

output from LuaLatex:

[image: output2]

Comment: Might be duplicate of [xetex - How to remove accents when using \MakeUppercase for Greek? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523691/how-to-remove-accents-when-using-makeuppercase-for-greek) but might want to consider which question has better answer.

Comment: About this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523691/how-to-remove-accents-when-using-makeuppercase-for-greek I noticed that using \usepackage[greek]{babel} in the preamble solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next `expl3` update will address this: see https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/2b91cfa676bf2a99fbfab63537b9e0bdcb612880 for the code detail. The approach is to use a simplified method for removing accents, based on that used by the `xgreek` package: with 8-bit engines, implementing the full Unicode algorithm is extremely challenging. It is likely that a future LaTeX release will auto-enable Greek support based on `babel`, but at the moment you will need to specify this even after the `expl3` code is released. A demonstration of both parts without the need for updates:

```latex
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}  
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand \MakeUppercase { o m }
  {
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
      { \text_uppercase:n {#2} }
      { \text_uppercase:nn {#1} {#2} }
  }
\group_begin:
  \bool_lazy_or:nnF
    { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: }
    { \sys_if_engine_xetex_p: }
    {
      \cs_set_protected:Npn \__text_loop:nn #1#2
        {
          \quark_if_recursion_tail_stop:n {#1}
          \use:x
            {
              \__text_tmp:w
                \char_to_utfviii_bytes:n { "#1 }
                \char_to_utfviii_bytes:n { "#2 }
            }
          \__text_loop:nn
        }
      \cs_set_protected:Npn \__text_tmp:w #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8
        {
          \tl_const:cx
            {
              c__text_uppercase_el_
              \char_generate:nn {#1} { 12 }
              \char_generate:nn {#2} { 12 }
              _tl
            }
            {
              \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
                \exp_not:N \char_generate:nn {#5} { 13 }
              \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
                \exp_not:N \char_generate:nn {#6} { 13 }
            }
        }
      \__text_loop:nn
        { 0370 } { 0370 }
        { 0371 } { 0370 }
        { 0372 } { 0372 }
        { 0373 } { 0372 }
        { 0376 } { 0376 }
        { 0377 } { 0376 }
        { 03FD } { 03FD }
        { 037B } { 03FD }
        { 03FE } { 03FE }
        { 037C } { 03FE }
        { 03FF } { 03FF }
        { 037D } { 03FF }
        { 0386 } { 0391 }
        { 0388 } { 0395 }
        { 0389 } { 0397 }
        { 038A } { 0399 }
        { 038C } { 039F }
        { 038E } { 03A5 }
        { 038F } { 03A9 }
        { 0390 } { 03AA }
        { 0391 } { 0391 }
        { 0392 } { 0392 }
        { 0393 } { 0393 }
        { 0394 } { 0394 }
        { 0395 } { 0395 }
        { 0396 } { 0396 }
        { 0397 } { 0397 }
        { 0398 } { 0398 }
        { 0399 } { 0399 }
        { 039A } { 039A }
        { 039B } { 039B }
        { 039C } { 039C }
        { 039D } { 039D }
        { 039E } { 039E }
        { 039F } { 039F }
        { 03A0 } { 03A0 }
        { 03A1 } { 03A1 }
        { 03A3 } { 03A3 }
        { 03A4 } { 03A4 }
        { 03A5 } { 03A5 }
        { 03A6 } { 03A6 }
        { 03A7 } { 03A7 }
        { 03A8 } { 03A8 }
        { 03A9 } { 03A9 }
        { 03AA } { 03AA }
        { 03AB } { 03AB }
        { 03AC } { 0391 }
        { 03AD } { 0395 }
        { 03AE } { 0397 }
        { 03AF } { 0399 }
        { 03B0 } { 03AB }
        { 03B1 } { 0391 }
        { 03B2 } { 0392 }
        { 03B3 } { 0393 }
        { 03B4 } { 0394 }
        { 03B5 } { 0395 }
        { 03B6 } { 0396 }
        { 03B7 } { 0397 }
        { 03B8 } { 0398 }
        { 03B9 } { 0399 }
        { 03BA } { 039A }
        { 03BB } { 039B }
        { 03BC } { 039C }
        { 03BD } { 039D }
        { 03BE } { 039E }
        { 03BF } { 039F }
        { 03C0 } { 03A0 }
        { 03C1 } { 03A1 }
        { 03C2 } { 03A3 }
        { 03C3 } { 03A3 }
        { 03C4 } { 03A4 }
        { 03C5 } { 03A5 }
        { 03C6 } { 03A6 }
        { 03C7 } { 03A7 }
        { 03C8 } { 03A8 }
        { 03C9 } { 03A9 }
        { 03CA } { 03AA }
        { 03CB } { 03AB }
        { 03CC } { 039F }
        { 03CD } { 03A5 }
        { 03CE } { 03A9 }
        { 03D0 } { 0392 }
        { 03D1 } { 0398 }
        { 03D2 } { 03A5 }
        { 03D3 } { 03A5 }
        { 03D4 } { 03AB }
        { 03D5 } { 03A6 }
        { 03D6 } { 03A0 }
        { 03DA } { 03DA }
        { 03DB } { 03DA }
        { 03DC } { 03DC }
        { 03DD } { 03DC }
        { 03DE } { 03DE }
        { 03DF } { 03DE }
        { 03E0 } { 03E0 }
        { 03E1 } { 03E0 }
        { 03F0 } { 039A }
        { 03F1 } { 03A1 }
        { 03F2 } { 03F9 }
        { 03F9 } { 03F9 }
        \q_recursion_tail ?
        \q_recursion_stop
      \cs_set_protected:Npn \__text_tmp:w #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8
        {
          \tl_const:cx
            {
              c__text_uppercase_el_
              \char_generate:nn {#1} { 12 }
              \char_generate:nn {#2} { 12 }
              \char_generate:nn {#3} { 12 }
              _tl
            }
            {
              \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
                \exp_not:N \char_generate:nn {#5} { 13 }
              \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
                \exp_not:N \char_generate:nn {#6} { 13 }
              \tl_if_blank:nF {#7}
                {
                  \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN \exp_after:wN
                    \exp_not:N \char_generate:nn {#7} { 13 }
                }
            }
        }
      \__text_loop:nn
        { 1F00 } { 0391 }
        { 1F01 } { 0391 }
        { 1F02 } { 0391 }
        { 1F03 } { 0391 }
        { 1F04 } { 0391 }
        { 1F05 } { 0391 }
        { 1F06 } { 0391 }
        { 1F07 } { 0391 }
        { 1F08 } { 0391 }
        { 1F09 } { 0391 }
        { 1F0A } { 0391 }
        { 1F0B } { 0391 }
        { 1F0C } { 0391 }
        { 1F0D } { 0391 }
        { 1F0E } { 0391 }
        { 1F0F } { 0391 }
        { 1F10 } { 0395 }
        { 1F11 } { 0395 }
        { 1F12 } { 0395 }
        { 1F13 } { 0395 }
        { 1F14 } { 0395 }
        { 1F15 } { 0395 }
        { 1F18 } { 0395 }
        { 1F19 } { 0395 }
        { 1F1A } { 0395 }
        { 1F1B } { 0395 }
        { 1F1C } { 0395 }
        { 1F1D } { 0395 }
        { 1F20 } { 0397 }
        { 1F21 } { 0397 }
        { 1F22 } { 0397 }
        { 1F23 } { 0397 }
        { 1F24 } { 0397 }
        { 1F25 } { 0397 }
        { 1F26 } { 0397 }
        { 1F27 } { 0397 }
        { 1F28 } { 0397 }
        { 1F29 } { 0397 }
        { 1F2A } { 0397 }
        { 1F2B } { 0397 }
        { 1F2C } { 0397 }
        { 1F2D } { 0397 }
        { 1F2E } { 0397 }
        { 1F2F } { 0397 }
        { 1F30 } { 0399 }
        { 1F31 } { 0399 }
        { 1F32 } { 0399 }
        { 1F33 } { 0399 }
        { 1F34 } { 0399 }
        { 1F35 } { 0399 }
        { 1F36 } { 0399 }
        { 1F37 } { 0399 }
        { 1F38 } { 0399 }
        { 1F39 } { 0399 }
        { 1F3A } { 0399 }
        { 1F3B } { 0399 }
        { 1F3C } { 0399 }
        { 1F3D } { 0399 }
        { 1F3E } { 0399 }
        { 1F3F } { 0399 }
        { 1F40 } { 039F }
        { 1F41 } { 039F }
        { 1F42 } { 039F }
        { 1F43 } { 039F }
        { 1F44 } { 039F }
        { 1F45 } { 039F }
        { 1F48 } { 039F }
        { 1F49 } { 039F }
        { 1F4A } { 039F }
        { 1F4B } { 039F }
        { 1F4C } { 039F }
        { 1F4D } { 039F }
        { 1F50 } { 03A5 }
        { 1F51 } { 03A5 }
        { 1F52 } { 03A5 }
        { 1F53 } { 03A5 }
        { 1F54 } { 03A5 }
        { 1F55 } { 03A5 }
        { 1F56 } { 03A5 }
        { 1F57 } { 03A5 }
        { 1F59 } { 03A5 }
        { 1F5B } { 03A5 }
        { 1F5D } { 03A5 }
        { 1F5F } { 03A5 }
        { 1F60 } { 03A9 }
        { 1F61 } { 03A9 }
        { 1F62 } { 03A9 }
        { 1F63 } { 03A9 }
        { 1F64 } { 03A9 }
        { 1F65 } { 03A9 }
        { 1F66 } { 03A9 }
        { 1F67 } { 03A9 }
        { 1F68 } { 03A9 }
        { 1F69 } { 03A9 }
        { 1F6A } { 03A9 }
        { 1F6B } { 03A9 }
        { 1F6C } { 03A9 }
        { 1F6D } { 03A9 }
        { 1F6E } { 03A9 }
        { 1F6F } { 03A9 }
        { 1F70 } { 0391 }
        { 1F71 } { 0391 }
        { 1F72 } { 0395 }
        { 1F73 } { 0395 }
        { 1F74 } { 0397 }
        { 1F75 } { 0397 }
        { 1F76 } { 0399 }
        { 1F77 } { 0399 }
        { 1F78 } { 039F }
        { 1F79 } { 039F }
        { 1F7A } { 03A5 }
        { 1F7B } { 03A5 }
        { 1F7C } { 03A9 }
        { 1F7D } { 03A9 }
        { 1F80 } { 1FBC }
        { 1F81 } { 1FBC }
        { 1F82 } { 1FBC }
        { 1F83 } { 1FBC }
        { 1F84 } { 1FBC }
        { 1F85 } { 1FBC }
        { 1F86 } { 1FBC }
        { 1F87 } { 1FBC }
        { 1F88 } { 1FBC }
        { 1F89 } { 1FBC }
        { 1F8A } { 1FBC }
        { 1F8B } { 1FBC }
        { 1F8C } { 1FBC }
        { 1F8D } { 1FBC }
        { 1F8E } { 1FBC }
        { 1F8F } { 1FBC }
        { 1F90 } { 1FCC }
        { 1F91 } { 1FCC }
        { 1F92 } { 1FCC }
        { 1F93 } { 1FCC }
        { 1F94 } { 1FCC }
        { 1F95 } { 1FCC }
        { 1F96 } { 1FCC }
        { 1F97 } { 1FCC }
        { 1F98 } { 1FCC }
        { 1F99 } { 1FCC }
        { 1F9A } { 1FCC }
        { 1F9B } { 1FCC }
        { 1F9C } { 1FCC }
        { 1F9D } { 1FCC }
        { 1F9E } { 1FCC }
        { 1F9F } { 1FCC }
        { 1FA0 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FA1 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FA2 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FA3 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FA4 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FA5 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FA6 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FA7 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FA8 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FA9 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FAA } { 1FFC }
        { 1FAB } { 1FFC }
        { 1FAC } { 1FFC }
        { 1FAD } { 1FFC }
        { 1FAE } { 1FFC }
        { 1FAF } { 1FFC }
        { 1FB0 } { 1FB8 }
        { 1FB1 } { 1FB9 }
        { 1FB2 } { 1FBC }
        { 1FB3 } { 1FBC }
        { 1FB4 } { 1FBC }
        { 1FB6 } { 0391 }
        { 1FB7 } { 1FBC }
        { 1FB8 } { 1FB8 }
        { 1FB9 } { 1FB9 }
        { 1FBA } { 0391 }
        { 1FBB } { 0391 }
        { 1FBC } { 1FBC }
        { 1FBD } { 1FBD }
        { 1FC2 } { 1FCC }
        { 1FC3 } { 1FCC }
        { 1FC4 } { 1FCC }
        { 1FC6 } { 0397 }
        { 1FC7 } { 1FCC }
        { 1FC8 } { 0395 }
        { 1FC9 } { 0395 }
        { 1FCA } { 0397 }
        { 1FCB } { 0397 }
        { 1FCC } { 1FCC }
        { 1FD0 } { 1FD8 }
        { 1FD1 } { 1FD9 }
        { 1FD2 } { 03AA }
        { 1FD3 } { 03AA }
        { 1FD6 } { 0399 }
        { 1FD7 } { 03AA }
        { 1FD8 } { 1FD8 }
        { 1FD9 } { 1FD9 }
        { 1FDA } { 0399 }
        { 1FDB } { 0399 }
        { 1FE0 } { 1FE8 }
        { 1FE1 } { 1FE9 }
        { 1FE2 } { 03AB }
        { 1FE3 } { 03AB }
        { 1FE4 } { 03A1 }
        { 1FE5 } { 03A1 }
        { 1FE6 } { 03A5 }
        { 1FE7 } { 03AB }
        { 1FE8 } { 1FE8 }
        { 1FE9 } { 1FE9 }
        { 1FEA } { 03A5 }
        { 1FEB } { 03A5 }
        { 1FEC } { 1FEC }
        { 1FF2 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FF3 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FF4 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FF6 } { 03A9 }
        { 1FF7 } { 1FFC }
        { 1FF8 } { 039F }
        { 1FF9 } { 039F }
        { 1FFA } { 03A9 }
        { 1FFB } { 03A9 }
        { 1FFC } { 1FFC }
        \q_recursion_tail ?
        \q_recursion_stop
    }
\group_end:
  \bool_lazy_or:nnF
    { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: }
    { \sys_if_engine_xetex_p: }
    {
      \cs_new:Npn \__text_change_case_upper_el:nnnN #1#2#3#4
        {
          \int_compare:nNnTF { `#4 } > { "80 }
            {
              \int_compare:nNnTF { `#4 } < { "E0 }
                { \__text_change_case_upper_el:nnnNN }
                {
                   \int_compare:nNnTF { `#4 } < { "F0 }
                    { \__text_change_case_upper_el:nnnNNN }
                    { \__text_change_case_char:nnnN }
                }
            }
            { \__text_change_case_char:nnnN }
               {#1} {#2} {#3} #4
        }
      \cs_new:Npn \__text_change_case_upper_el:nnnNN #1#2#3#4#5
        { \__text_change_case_upper_el:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4#5} }
      \cs_new:Npn \__text_change_case_upper_el:nnnNNN #1#2#3#4#5#6
        { \__text_change_case_upper_el:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4#5#6} }
      \cs_new:Npn \__text_change_case_upper_el:nnnn #1#2#3#4
        {
          \cs_if_exist:cTF { c__text_uppercase_el_ \tl_to_str:n {#4} _tl }
            {
              \__text_change_case_store:v
                { c__text_uppercase_el_ \tl_to_str:n {#4} _tl }
              \__text_change_case_loop:nnw {#1} {#3}
            }
            { \__text_change_case_char:nnnN {#1} {#2} {#3} #4 }
        }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\MakeUppercase[el]{Πρόταση για έλεγχο των τόνων στα κεφαλαία }
\end{document}
```

Once the `expl3` update is out, all you'll need is the part

```latex
\DeclareDocumentCommand \MakeUppercase { o m }
  {
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
      { \text_uppercase:n {#2} }
      { \text_uppercase:nn {#1} {#2} }
  }
```

plus the `\MakeUppercase[el]` idea.

Comment: This is indeed a very nice piece of code, and it works perfectly. It would be great especially for us who use mostly the Greek language, this code (and as you mentioned the features of babel for Greek) to be embedded in a near future LaTeX release. We have to wait for this, and for the update of expl3.

Comment: @MiltosP. The `expl3` change will be out in a few days: the adjustment to `\MakeUppercase` may take a bit longer

Comment: Notable here is that `babel`'s current approach will break titlecasing in Greek: better with the new case changer would be to redefine `\MakeUppercase` in the Unicode situation too: hopefully this can be agree for the Fall '22 release.

Answer (score 5):

Note `\MakeUppercase` had a big upgrade in the June2022 release, this applies to the current release mostly.

The Unicode data files show accented letters as uppercase, which doesn't always match what is wanted. You can locally disable the accents in pdflatex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{calc}  
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,247mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{gfsartemisia}  
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[english, greek]{babel}  


\begin{document}      
Πρόταση για έλεγχο των τόνων στα κεφαλαία  

{\let\acctonos\relax 
\MakeUppercase{Πρόταση για έλεγχο των τόνων στα κεφαλαία}}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Q: `\acctonos` ?

Comment: @John tonos accent see `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-inputenc/lgrenc.dfu` or equivalent path

Comment: If you know this upgrade is going to be applied in LuaLatex and XeLatex also?

Comment: @MiltosP. makeuppercase changed in all engines, se latex news 35. Unicode engines have more complete support for some aspects

Comment: This is a place we likely want language tailoring: Greek is 'interesting' as there are uppercase accented letters, they are just not used in Greek!