# Something is going wrong with the greek "o" letter, Babel and making uppercase. How can I fix it?

Tags: errors, babel, greek, uppercase

Please consider the following PdfLatex compilable code, which just converts a sentence in Greek from lowercase to uppercase letters with two ways, the traditional one and a new one ([see link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652506/command-makeuppercase-does-not-work-as-expected-in-pdflatex-but-works-fine-in)). But if I uncomment the `\usepackage{babel}` line I get error and the Greek o's are not printed. What's going on? This is something I used many times and I never got any errors.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}
    Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία
    
\MakeUppercase{Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία}
    
\let\acctonos\relax\MakeUppercase{Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have tried to put `\usepackage[greek, provide=*]{babel}`?

Comment: @Sebastiano I guess this should be an answer.

Comment: @egreg Good morning. Yes it is an answer. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano: Yes, it works, and I could accept it as an answer if you post it.

Comment: @miltos Don't worry about the publication of my answer. The important thing is that we have solved the problem. You can put the answer yourself :-) by copying from my comment. :-)

Comment: All true but something is obviously not quite right: I'll add to my to-do list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that may be interested in the solution of the above issue, after the suggestion of the community member Sebastiano the issue can be bypassed by:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={180mm,257mm},left=15mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek,provide=*]{babel} % <-- Note the change!

\begin{document}
    Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία
    
\MakeUppercase{Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία}
    
\let\acctonos\relax\MakeUppercase{Μικρό Κείμενο για τον έλεγχο της μετατροπής των πεζών σε κεφαλαία}

\end{document}
```